# Use of Global picards theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider $y'=1+xy, y(0)=0 \:on\: [-b,b]$. Use the global Picards theorem to show there is a unique solution for any $b\lt \infty$.

Ok so for $f,g$ that satisfy the conditions

$\parallel Tf(x) - Tg(x)\parallel =| \int_0^xs(f(s)-g(s))ds|\\\le\parallel f-g\parallel_{\infty}\int_0^x|s|ds \le \parallel f-g\parallel_{\infty}\frac{|b|^2}{2}$

but im not sure where to go from here, any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for small $x$, use the contraction mapping theorem. To extend for all $x\in[-b,b]$, use inequality $y'<1+by$ which leads to $y'<1+by$, then to the apriori estimate $|y|<exp(bx)<exp(b^2)$. So the solution is bounded and, hence, can be extended towards all interval $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: Inequality y'<1+by implies $y(x)\leq b+b\int_0^x y(s)ds$, which yields $|y|\leq b e^{bx}\leq be^{b^2}$. This apriori boundedness estimate allows to extend the solution to the entire real line.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).